# Is it possible to extrapolate a black body radiation graph of the visible spectrum of a light bulb into the infrared and uv spectrum?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, everyday-life, thermal-radiation, spectroscopy

If the colour spectrum graph in the visible spectrum is plotted, is it possible to use a specific equation to extrapolate the curve? What if it's a light bulb that isn't a black body (CFL, LED)? Would the equations still apply?

Comment: As you stated yourself, CFLs/LED bulbs do not produce light by blackbody radiation. So no, you cannot use the equations for blackbody radiation for CFLs/LEDs.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to extrapolate. The black body equations can be used to calculate the intensity at all wavelengths. This image shows the black body radiation for a regular light bulb.[image]

The gray strip represents the visible spectrum. IR region is to the right of that strip (longer wavelengths) As you can see much of the light it emits is in the IR region and very little in the UV.

Comment: It might be worth noting (if my memory is correct)  that the black body curves for the same body at different temperatures don't cross reach other. If the 6000K and 3000K lines were for the same object, the 6000K one would be higher than the 3000K one at all wavelengths

Comment: @PhillS  Your memory has failed you.  The blackbody curve never hits zero for any temperature, hence they must cross each other.

Comment: Yes, you can fit the blackbody curve to a light bulb, but no it will not be accurate at all wavelengths.  The envelope of the light bulb blocks UV wavelengths.   The model will be ok in the visible and IR (to a point).  The BB curve cannot be used to model a CFL or LED bulb.

Comment: Which equation could I use? Do the equations apply to any black body, regardless of the source? @garyp

Comment: @garyp actually they indeed don't cross: due to Stefan-Boltzmann law the higher temperature curve will be all above the lower temperature one. See e.g. [this plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Black_body.svg) of 3000 K, 4000 K and 5000 K black body spectra.